# Eager Loading in .Net4 Link-to-EF; maybe like DataLoadOptions

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-4, eager-loading

I am using VS2010 .Net4 Linq-to-EntityFramework and would like to explicitly eager load some child data.  I would like to provide functionality similar to that of **DataLoadOptions** or **LoadWith** which are available for Linq-to-SQL IIUC, but are not available to Linq-to-EF.

(As an aside, this is so that I can record data to be played back later during testing.  We have used lazy loading and I need to find these occurrences and replace with eager loading.  The **DataLoadOptions** method would allow a clean way to implement this.)

I am trying to provide a typesafe eager loading scheme as described at [MosesOfEgypt blog](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Introducing-DataLoadOptions-for-Entity-Framework-ObjectContext.aspx).  I have modified the generation of T4 and have what I think is the last problem.  In .Net4, the entity properties return **ObjectSet**.  But unfortunately, the **Include** function returns **ObjectQuery** which is the base class for **ObjectSet**.

Here is a subset of the ObjectContext class as generated from modified T4 template:

```
    #region DataLoadOptions Functionality

            public DataLoadOptions LoadOptions { get; set; }

            private ObjectSet<TEntity> ApplyDataLoadOptions<TEntity>(string queryString) where TEntity : class
            {
                var query = CreateObjectSet<TEntity>(queryString);

                if (LoadOptions != null)
                {
                    var members = LoadOptions.GetPreloadedMembers<TEntity>();

                    foreach (var member in members)
                    {
 **********              query = query.Include(member.Name);
                    }
                }
                return query;
            }

    #endregion



    #region ObjectSet Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        public ObjectSet<Address> Addresses
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_Addresses == null))
                {
                    _Addresses = ApplyDataLoadOptions<Address>("Addresses");
                }
                return _Addresses;
            }
        }

    #endregion
```

The line starting with "*******" is where the cast from **ObjectQuery** to **ObjectSet** occurs.  ANd this is an invalid upcast so if explicitly cast at designtime, will fail at runtime, unless I'm doing it wrong.

One solution might be to write an extension method for **ObjectSet.Include** so that it returns **ObjectSet** instead of **ObjectQuery**.  I would like to know how to find the source code of the **ObjectQuery.Include** function, if that is possible.  And I'm not sure if these solution would work.

Also wonder if there was a way to upcast the results of the **Include** function from **ObjectQuery** to **ObjectSet**.  Again, not sure if this would work.

Any help on implementing a DataLoadOptions capability for Linq-to-EF in .Net4 would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what your asking here.

`.Include` returns an `ObjectQuery<T>`, which implements `IQueryable<T>`. Why do you want to cast it as `ObjectSet<T>`??

WRT "strongly-typed" `Include`'s, the short answer is you can't. But you can make it sweeter with the syntactic sugary of extension methods.

We create **enumerations** for each entity (may be overkill, but i hate magic strings), which contain each association. Our Repository accepts an array of these enumerations. We then use an extension method on the enumeration to convert to an `Include`.

Example (simplified) Repository code:

```
public ICollection<Order> GetOrdersWithUser(Expression<Func<Order,bool>> predicate, OrderAssocations[] includes)
{
   return _ctx.Orders.WithAssociations(includes).Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

And the extension:

```
public static ObjectQuery<Order> WithAssociations(this ObjectQuery<Order> source, OrderAssociations[] includes)
{
   var query = source;

   foreach (var include in includes)
   {
      query = query.Include(include.ToNavigationalProperty()));
   }

   return query;
}
```

`.ToNavigationalProperty()` is another extension method on the enumeration, which simply returns the matching Navigational property.

Comment: I am trying to provide a typesafe eager loading scheme as described at MosesOfEgypt blog.  The code at that site was written for a beta version and does not seem quite compatible with the released version of .net4.  (http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Introducing-DataLoadOptions-for-Entity-Framework-ObjectContext.aspx)  It seems I need the function to return ObjectSet instead of ObjectQuery---- WAS: private ObjectQuery<TEntity> ApplyDataLoadOptions<TEntity>(string queryString) NOW: private ObjectSet<TEntity> ApplyDataLoadOptions<TEntity>(string queryString)

Comment: A very interesting approach. However, `ObjectQuery<T>` implements `IQueryable<T>`. When you do `.Include`, your returning an `ObjectQuery<T>`, there is no way to bring this back to an `ObjectSet<T>` (maybe if you did an explicit cast, not sure). Does his approach not work?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question... however, here is how I have done "dynamic" eager loading:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Flags to indicate which child entities to eager load
    /// </summary>
    [Flags]
    public enum IncludeFlags
    {
        None = 1,
        All = 1 << 1,
        ChildEntity1 = 1 << 2,
        ChildEntity2 = 1 << 3,
        ChildEntity3 = 1 << 4
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to create my object query
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">Database context</param>
    /// <param name="includeFlags">Indicates which flags to Include</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static ObjectQuery<MyEntity> GetContext(DataBaseContext context, IncludeFlags includeFlags)
    {
        ObjectQuery<MyEntity> query = new ObjectQuery<MyEntity>("MyEntity", context);

        if ((includeFlags & IncludeFlags.None) != IncludeFlags.None)
        {
            bool getAll = ((includeFlags & IncludeFlags.All) == IncludeFlags.All);
            if (getAll || ((includeFlags & IncludeFlags.ChildEntity1) == IncludeFlags.ChildEntity1))
                query = query.Include("ChildEntity1");

            if (getAll || ((includeFlags & IncludeFlags.ChildEntity2) == IncludeFlags.ChildEntity2))
                query = query.Include("ChildEntity2");

            if (getAll || ((includeFlags & IncludeFlags.ChildEntity3) == IncludeFlags.ChildEntity3))
                query = query.Include("ChildEntity2.ChildEntity3");
        }

        return query;
    }

    public static MyEntity[] GetMyEntities(IncludeFlags flags = IncludeFlags.None)
    {
        DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext();
        from e in GetContext(db, flags)
        select e;

        return e.ToArray();
    }

    public void GetMyEntities()
    {
        MyEntity[] entities = Test.GetMyEntities(); // Does not load any child entities
        MyEntity[] entities2 = Test.GetMyEntities(IncludeFlags.All); // Loads them all
        MyEntity[] entities3 = Test.GetMyEntities(IncludeFlags.ChildEntity1 | IncludeFlags.ChildEntity2); // Only loads child 1 and 2
        MyEntity[] entities4 = Test.GetMyEntities(IncludeFlags.ChildEntity3); // Only loads ChildEntity2.ChildEntity3
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: We have many users of our project that contains the linq-to-EF queries, which accept a previously created DatabaseContext.  I was hoping to find a mechanism that would allow me to subclass my DatabaseContext by adding the DataLoadOptions extension; while not affecting others use of the same code.  

So this is a great solution, but is not ideal for my scenario.  I should have made that more clear up front.  Thanks.   (BTW, I'd vote for your post but I"m a newbie and don't have enough points yet)